# Non-nullable instance field 'Welcome' must be initialized Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to call API's in flutter but when I am defining the variable _Welcome I am getting this error. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
class _PostsPageState extends State<PostsPage> {
Future<Welcome> _Welcome; //error here


@override
void initState() {
_Welcome = API_Manager().getNews();
super.initState();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Future` is not used with the `late` keyword, so the Dart analyzer expects it to be instantly initialized.

Either do:

```dart
late Future<Welcome>. _Welcome;

@override
void initState() {
_Welcome = API_Manager().getNews();
super.initState();
}
```

or just at the start:

```dart
Future<Welcome> _Welcome = API_Manager().getNews();
```

Comment: That doesn't make any sense to me. In the constructor, I explicitly *assign* to that field. How is it *not initialized* then?

Comment: A related issue on GitHub: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/2224

Comment: @m93a your issue is a different issue than this one since this one is within a state class, so no point commenting here really

Answer (score 0):

This error due to the null-safety property of flutter. So, what is null-safety? Flutter null safety is the feature that became available after the release of version 2. This feature helps to improve developers' productivity by eliminating a whole class of bugs caused by null dereferencing errors. So, how can you solve this problem? Actually, there are many options for that; you can initialize the variable at the time of the declaration, or you can use `late` keyword such as `late Future<Welcome> _Welcome;`

Answer (score 0):

try `late Future<Welcome> _Welcome;`

With this you promise to the compiler that it is initialized when it's accessed later on.
Since you assing it directly in the `initState` that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use `late Future<Welcome> _welcome;`